# How to make DS.belongsTo working with ember-data and django-tastypie

Tags: ember.js, tastypie, ember-data

Can't imagine why I can't get related item for and model item.

I have a models

```
App.Staple = DS.Model.extend({
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    album: DS.belongsTo('App.Album')
});

App.Album = DS.Model.extend({
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    staples: DS.hasMany('App.Staple')
});
```

connected to django-tastypie.
Samples of data:

GET /api/v1/staple/1/

```
{"album_id": "/api/v1/album/1/", "created": "2012-12-27T11:14:38.320364", "description": "asdlfkjasldkfj", "id": 1, "lead_count": 0, "rank": 0, "resource_uri": "/api/v1/staple/1/", "slug": "slug", "status": "public"}
```

GET /api/v1/album/1/

```
{"album_staples": ["/api/v1/staple/1/"], "created": "2012-12-27T11:14:23.433934", "description": "", "followed_count": 0, "id": 1, "name": "Album Staple", "rank": 0, "resource_uri": "/api/v1/album/1/", "slug": "staple_album", "status": "public"}
```

The problem is that

```
console.log(App.Staple.find(1).get('album'))
```

gives null.

Hovewer

```
App.Album.find(1).get('staples')
```

return items ok.

Full js code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/zczyX/

Comment: That fiddle is missing the references to: jQuery, Handlebars, Ember, Ember Data, django-tastypie data adapter. Your fiddle is also missing all the handlebar templates, and you're running it under Mootools.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in ember-data-tastypie-adapter.
It's fixed now.